# .equals and .get used together

Tags: java, jpa

the problem im having is with .equals. im trying to check if the password string equals the value of password in the database. I have the password string in my serlvet and it gets the password from a form. it checks the username fine but not the password

```
public boolean acceptCustomer(String username, String password){
CustomerTableClass customer = new CustomerTableClass();
customer.setCustomerUsername(username);
customer.setCustomerPassword(password);
Boolean check = null;
try
{
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();             
CustomerTableClass customerTest = new CustomerTableClass();
customerTest = entityManager.find(customer.getClass(),username);
if (customerTest!=null)&&(password.equals(customer.getPassword()))){

check= true; 
System.out.println("User found");

}
```

Comment: Did you check the value returned by the getPassword method? because I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: So what does the debugger say are the values of `password` and `customer.getPassword()`? What other diagnosis steps have you done?

Comment: Also, please format your code samples.

Comment: Yet another place where passwords are stored in plain text in the database. Don't do this. Use bcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra bracket it seems. Try this:

```
(customerTest!=null && password.equals(customer.getPassword() ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your password field is probably encoded in some kind of [hash](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/sample-hashes). You'll want to hash the password the user has passed in on the login form, and THEN check it against the password you fetched from the database. Your database password may also have a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography). If it has a salt then you'll need to append the salt to the password passed in by the user, then has it, then compare it against the password in the database.

Answer (score 0):

the customer.getPassword() was not get the password from the database. i had to find and retrieve the password before using it in the .equals. its working perfectly now heres the code

```
    public boolean acceptCustomer(String username, String password){
    CustomerTableClass customer = new CustomerTableClass();
    customer.setCustomerUsername(username);
    customer.setCustomerPassword(password);
    Boolean check = null;

    try 
    {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();             
        CustomerTableClass customerTest = new CustomerTableClass();
        customerTest = entityManager.find(customer.getClass(),username);// .find checks if username aleady exists 
        if (customerTest!=null ){// if user exists
            customer = entityManager.find(customer.getClass(), username);// retrieve user from db
            customer.getPassword();//retrieve password from db
            if (password.equals(customer.getPassword()))//if they are equal 
            {
                System.out.println("user and password correct");
                check= true;    
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("user and password not correct");
                check= false;
                entityManager.close();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("user does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're closing the entityManager I would think you'd want to do that at the bottom of your try {} block and probably in a finally {} clause